# Variable length array with GCC flag "-Wlarger-than=len"

Tags: c, gcc

I really do not know which should be the right Title for this, but I will try to explain it as much as I can, please be patient with me.

Today I discovered this `GCC` flag =>> `-Wlarger-than=len`:

```
Warn whenever an object of larger than len bytes is defined.
```

So I decided to give it a try. Lets take a look at the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char ptr[12] = "Mississippi";
    size_t len1 = sizeof ptr;

    printf("Len1 = %zu\n", len1);

    char a[len1];
    strcpy(a, ptr);

    printf("\nA = %s\n", a);
}
```

Which returns as Output:

```
Len1 = 12

A = Mississippi
```

So the program looks fine, but if I turn the `-Wlarger-than=len` Flag ON with `len == 10` instead 12:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wlarger-than=10 program.c -o program
```

I get 16 when I was execpecting 12:

```
program.c:5:14: error: size of ‘ptr’ is 12 bytes [-Werror=larger-than=]
         char ptr[12] = "Mississippi";
              ^~~
program.c:10:14: error: size of ‘({anonymous})’ is 16 bytes [-Werror=larger-than=]
         char a[len1];
              ^
program.c:10:14: error: size of ‘({anonymous})’ is 16 bytes [-Werror=larger-than=]
program.c:10:14: error: size of ‘({anonymous})’ is 16 bytes [-Werror=larger-than=]
program.c:10:14: error: size of ‘({anonymous})’ is 16 bytes [-Werror=larger-than=]
```

Why is happening this? I'm confused about this, because this line:

```
char a[len1];
```

I though that it will be:

```
char a[12];
```

Same thing happens if I change`size_t len1 = sizeof ptr;` to `size_t len1 = strlen(ptr) + 1;`

Comment: Late comment but gcc have this flag -Wvla-larger-than=<byte-size> which will warn you about vla sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `a` is a variable length array (VLA). Obviously, the compiler cannot predict the future run-time size of a VLA, which means that `-Wlarger-than=len` option cannot and will not issue warnings that would apply to VLA arrays themselves. Despite your expectations, the warning you see does not directly apply to your array `a` and is not triggered by the size of `a` itself.

Variable length array is implemented under the hood though some implementation-dependent internal data type, which just happens to have size 16 in GCC. One can guess that on your platform this internal data type includes a 8-byte pointer to array memory as well as 8-byte run-time size information. This is where size 16 comes from. If you experiment more your with your code you will see that the size does not depend on the value of `len1` at all. The size is always 16.

The warning that you receive applies to that specific stack-allocated anonymous object of that internal type. This is why the error message says `‘({anonymous})’` instead of `a`. You can basically say that using `-Wlarger-than=len` option with `len` smaller than 16 will always trigger that diagnostic for each and every VLA.

I.e. your

```
char a[len1];
```

is not equivalent to

```
char a[12];
```

as you seem to believe. It is actually fairly equivalent to something like

```
struct anonymous_t {
  char *data;
  size_t size;
} anonymous = { alloca(len1), len1 };
```

And every time you access `a[i]` the compiler actually accesses `anonymous.data[i]`. The message you see complains about the size of `anonymous`, not about the size of your `a`.

Comment: I just noticed that here `-Wlarger-than=len`, len should be `>=` 16 and works fine and the only warning will be `error: size of ‘ptr’ is 22 bytes` if I say something like `char ptr[] = "Arnold-Schwarzenegger";`

Comment: I don't think there is necessarily a pointer allocated, or even the length. Maybe it is just that the alignmentment requires a 8 or 16 byte alignement, thus the smallest size for the VLA would be 16 (or 8 if there is the length stored). A look at the generated code should clarify. (Or maybe there is some information about how gcc manages VLAs on that architecture)

Comment: Gcc have this Wvla-larger-than=<byte-size> which will warn about vla sizes.